# In what situation, if we add sorted numbers as keys to a hash table, we can expect the hash to be ordered?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, hash

Is it true that in PHP, when we insert elements into a new hash table using sorted numbers as the keys, then the resulting hash will also be ordered?

So when we get the keys, they will be ordered, and `$a[0], $a[1], $a[2]` will also follow that original order?  (although certainly, the keys will be that order, but the values don't have to be).

Is it true that in PHP, we can count on that?  Is there no such behavior in Perl, Python, or Ruby?

Comment: It is valid under the situations defined by "The Fine Manual". If it isn't specifically stated, then don't rely on it.

Comment: Why do you want or need to rely on such behaviour?

Comment: @pst what is "The Fine Manual" -- you mean the ... PHP manual on http://php.net/manual/en/index.php ?

Comment: @Karl because if I already have some sorted numbers... let's say if they are in a linked list, or as the "values" in the array in PHP... and I need to use an algorithm to put these numbers into a hash table as the "keys"

Comment: I'm going to need you to be more detailed than that. A lot more. Start by describing the *problem you are going to solve* by arranging your data this way.

Comment: @JeremyL Depends on language. Consult the appropriate API/documentation, which should cover the behavior (and costs of operations on) the various data-types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html). Other languages have equivalents as well.

However, normally this behavior is not guaranteed for basic hash types (e.g. Python's `dict`) because it requires extra bookkeeping.

PHP's arrays are a special snowflake; it's best to not get into the habit of relying on basic hashes being ordered, even if you are working with PHP.

Comment: I believe (standard) Ruby 2 hashes are ordered based on insertion as well. Java has LinkedHashMap.

Comment: I think Perl has no way of sorting hashes, correct me if I'm wrong. You can of course do `foreach $key (sort keys %coins)`, but this is a trick involving sorting an array in fact. Pure hashes are not sorted by definition, since they're based on a hash function that has no order.

Comment: @m0skit0 No, you’re wrong.  Perl has various kinds of sorted hashes, but they all require more bookkeeping, at least internally, and thus are less efficient.

Comment: I would never describe anything in PHP as a *special snowflake*. Just **special** would probably suffice, however.

Comment: @Lattyware Indeed, snowflakes are pretty ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior in Perl is documented in [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html):

> The keys of a hash are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is subject to change in future versions of Perl, but it is guaranteed to be the same order as either the values or each function produces (given that the hash has not been modified). Since Perl 5.8.1 the ordering can be different even between different runs of Perl for security reasons (see [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks)).

You can use [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie%3a%3aIxHash):

> This Perl module implements Perl hashes that preserve the order in which the hash elements were added. The order is not affected when values corresponding to existing keys in the `IxHash` are changed. The elements can also be set to any arbitrary supplied order. The familiar Perl array operations can also be performed on the `IxHash`.

Comment: [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Hash::Indexed) is a faster alternative to IxHash.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Amber, the *collections.OrderedDict* is the Python tool guaranteed to preserve insertion order.

That said, I found the question as posed in the headline to be interesting.  An implementation detail of Python is that the hash values of integers is the value itself.  Since regular dicts (which are usually unordered) as just hash tables, it is sometimes possible to add sorted numbers to a dictionary has have them remain sorted:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(5)).keys()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(25)).keys()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(0,25,2)).keys()
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
>>> dict.fromkeys(sorted(sample(range(50), 40))).keys()
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 49]
```

This result is fragile and isn't a guaranteed behavior.  It relies on the following properties:

- keys are positioned according to their hash value modulo the dict size (that starts at 8)
- the hash values of integers are the integers themselves
- when hash table is two-thirds full, it get is resized upwards by a factor of four (upto 50,000 when it then starts doubling) and the existing key/value pairs get re-inserted.

> Question: In what situation, if we add sorted numbers as keys to a hash table,
>   we can expect the hash to be ordered?

Answer: Sorted numeric keys remain sorted in a regular dict if and only if those values remain sorted when taken modulo *n* for the size of the dictionary *and* if that condition also holds true for each of the smaller dictionaries created as elements are added:

- The first five elements (8 * 2 // 3) must be sorted when taken modulo 8.
- The first twenty-one elements (32* 2 // 3) must be sorted when taken modulo 32.
- The first eighty-five elements (128 * 2 // 3) must be sorted when taken module 128.
- and so on ...

In code:

```
def will_remain_sorted(seq):
    i, n = 0, 8
    while i < len(seq):
        i = n * 2 // 3
        if not sorted(seq[:i], key=lambda x: x%n) == seq[:i]:
            return False
        n *= 4 if n < 50000 else 2
    return True
```